Why is LiteDb Studio v5 failing to launch on Win 10
I started using LiteDb recently, and the latest (1.0.3) release of Studio was working fine in Win 10. Now, every time I try to run it, I get the below TypeInitializationException and I am unsure whether the issue is on my end or not. Here is my event log:
Log Name: Application
Source: .NET Runtime
Date: 9/10/2024 8:45:55 PM
Event ID: 1026
Task Category: None
Level: Error
Keywords: Classic
User: N/A
Computer: ######
Description:
Application: LiteDB.Studio.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateNewObject(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonObjectContract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty, 
...
at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]](System.String, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings)
at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]
at ICSharpCode.TextEditor.Util.AppSettingsManager..cctor()

Exception Info: System.TypeInitializationException
at ICSharpCode.TextEditor.Util.AppSettingsManager.get_ApplicationSettings()
at LiteDB.Studio.MainForm..ctor(System.String)
at LiteDB.Studio.Program.Main(System.String[])

I sought the event log but it did not really lead me anywhere. I also tried re-downloading the executable.

It is hard to tell from just that stack trace, but it looks like it is throwing an exception attempting to read some json application settings.  Is this a new version using older version config files?

I do not think so and there is no settings file available outside the executable. I'm thinking maybe something is going on on my end because it was working fine last week. And yes I abridged the stacktrace as it was just many more json calls when the appsettingmanager is trying to load.

Looks like you're not alone: https://github.com/mbdavid/LiteDB.Studio/issues/88

I suppose I can build it locally and try. Another reason I think it is on my end is I get the same behavior trying to launch another community dblite editor "ÖneBella".

@PeterB Yes, I posted that lol

Ah, well who knows, good luck.

I thought perhaps my db file was corrupting it and saw it somehow did not have the ".db" extension, but that was not it :( I remember I had the "remember last conn" checked and perhaps it was failing due to that...
